# How get paragraph number of specif text in Word VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need find an specific text in my document and get paragraph number position

This is for Excel VBA

```
Sub exportardatos()
'Paso 1: Declare las variables
Dim Paragraphe As Object, WordApp As Object, WordDoc As Object, WordTable As Object, WordRange As Object
File = "C:\Users\lper\Documents\FormExp.docx"

 On Error Resume Next

    'creationsession Word
    Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
    Err.Clear
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")

      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordApp.Activate
    'open the file .doc
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(File)


    'Word Enumerated Constants
    Const wdReplaceAll = 2
        WordApp.Documents("FormExp.docx").Activate
        Dim nParag As Long
        Set WordRange = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range

        For Each WordRange In WordDoc.StoryRanges
         With WordApp.Selection.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                .Text = "Legal"
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute
                Do While .Execute = True
                nParag = WordRange(0, Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.End).Paragraphs.Count
                MsgBox (nParag)
                Loop

         End With
        Next WordRange

EndRoutine:
        'Optimize Code
          Application.ScreenUpdating = True
          Application.EnableEvents = True

        'Clear The Clipboard
          Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Set WordDoc = Nothing
    'Set WordApp = Nothing
MsgBox ("Ready")
End Sub
```

I get code error 438

Comment: Which instruction is throwing error 438 specifically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a quick example of how to get the paragraph number. Notice that you don't have to `Activate` the Word document to get this to work.

```
Public Sub Exportardatos()
    Dim filename As String
    filename = "C:\Users\lper\Documents\FormExp.docx"

    Dim wordApp As Object
    Set wordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
    If wordApp Is Nothing Then
        Set wordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Microsoft Word cannot be found!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Dim searchRange As Object
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(filename)
    Set searchRange = wordDoc.Range

    With searchRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "Legal"
        .Wrap = 0                     '=wdFindStop
        While .Execute(FindText:="Legal", Forward:=True)
            If .found Then
                Debug.Print "found in paragraph " & GetParNum(wordDoc, .Parent)
            End If
        Wend
    End With
End Sub

Function GetParNum(ByRef doc As Object, ByRef r As Object) As Integer
    '--- based on http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=59
    Dim rParagraphs As Object
    Dim CurPos As Long

    r.Select
    CurPos = doc.Bookmarks("\startOfSel").Start
    Set rParagraphs = doc.Range(Start:=0, End:=CurPos)
    GetParNum = rParagraphs.Paragraphs.Count
End Function
```